# FileManager4TinyMCE not seeing uploaded images

Tags: php, tinymce, file-manager

I made all settings as it says in the manual.
I created a folder and thumbs and I gave permission to write to it but can not see the pictures that uploaded the source folder.
I looked at the file "dialog.php" that displays pictures and noticed that
`$files = scandir ($root . $cur_dir);` returns **"FALSE"** even though the folder path is specified correctly and there's pictures
I would appreciate any suggestions

See more at: http://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/#sthash.ySH5z8IZ.dpuf

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, but it is a problem of your `/filemanager/config.php` (`$current_path`)

I also truncate the complete `/filemanager/thumbs` folder before change the config,
maybe also important don't know if really needed.

My tinymce folder Filemanager: `/admin/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager`
(so 6 subfolders to my root, see below => "../" )

My Folder Config (wrong):

```
// path from base_url to upload base dir
$upload_dir = '/_upload_bilder/_filemanager/';

// relative path from filemanager folder 
$current_path = '../../../../../../_filemanager/';
```

to upload files folder

then correct:

```
// path from base_url to upload base dir
$upload_dir = '/_upload_bilder/_filemanager/';

// relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
$current_path = '../../../../../../_upload_bilder/_filemanager/';
```

I hope that helps you :)

Best Regards
Tom

Answer (score 1):

i had a problem similar to this. the problem i had was

> There is an error! The root folder not exist

my file absolute path to filemanager plugin is:

```
    http://localhost/site/assets/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/thumb
```

my upload dir 
    /assets/uploads
so i took these steps to debug it.

- i changed line number 4 from

  ```
  $root = rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'/'); // don't touch this configuration
  ```

to

```
    $root = rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'site/','/'); // don't touch this configuration
```

- it worked but my images where not showing so i then updated my base_url, current_path, upload_dir to

  ```
  $base_url="http://localhost/site"; 
  $upload_dir = '/assets/uploads/'; 
  $current_path = '../../../uploads/';
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Line number 4 should not be change, just keep it the same then:

```
$base_url = "http://localhost/site"; 
$upload_dir = '/assets/uploads/'; //will be start from base url eg: http://localhost/site/assets/uploads/
$current_path = '../../../uploads/'; //will leave from filemanager folder to the same upload_dir
```